# Use dockerfile/mysql mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file error

Tags: mysql, docker

The following `docker run` command results in an unexpected error.

```
docker run --name mysql -d -v /data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql dockerfile/mysql
```

> Error:  150311 07:36:04 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with
>   databases from /var/lib/mysql 150311 07:36:04 mysqld_safe mysqld from
>   pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended

How can I solve it?

Comment: Does it work if you don't specify the `-v` argument?

Comment: it work very good if  don't specify the -v argument

Answer (score 0):

The permissions are wrong on the `/data/mysql` folder, so the mysql user in the container is unable to write to the directory. To fix this, you can either find the uid of the mysql user in the container and give it permissions to access the directory, or use a data container.

To find the uid, run:

`docker run dockerfile/mysql id -u mysql`

Then you can do something like `sudo chown ID /data/mysql` (where id is the UID) to give access to the mysql user.

To set up a data container see [the official docs.](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container)

Comment: I try use first way, failed

Answer (score 0):

If it is not for the production environment and is for local testing only then the simplest way to make it run is

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /data/mysql
```

This command is basically giving read and write permissions to all users for mysql folder.

Please let us know if this worked for you.

Comment: please go and check if /data/mysql has any files in it.

Comment: If it is not there it means that mounting is not done properly.A good way is to use official mysql repository https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mysql/ .
I have been using this official repository and it is working fine with mount points (i.e -v option)